# APK bigger than 50 MB

Tags: android, google-play

The limitation of an APK's size on the Android Market is now 50mb. However I'm doing an application which is really bigger.

The size of my app is due to videos. However even if I don't now if I'll make a free or paid app, I don't want anyone to be able to copy/re-use my videos. So I can't upload my videos on Internet and just download them from my app to copy them to the phone or sd card. In this case everyone would have acces to the file with all the videos.

Can we ask Google to accept a bigger app (with extra-cost if needed) ? Is there other solutions ?

Comment: please be mindful to us who are stuck with pre-app2sd handset and have small internal memory; apk is really easy to decompile (as a matter of fact, it's just a plain .zip file), and it would not take much skill to extract the video from your apk. If you want any sort of content protection, you must encrypt your content. And if you are already encrypting your content, why not put it as a downloadable in the internet?

Comment: But I've got no knowledge in encrypting yet :(. I've got no idea if it's hard... I think I'll use the solution with videos online and download them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unencrypted Video on APK

Here's what you're trying to do: you put an unencrypted video in your apk. Enlarging the size of the apk, and exceeding Google Market's limit.

**How to beat the scheme:** a rooted user need to extract the apk, unzip the apk, and post your video on Youtube for everyone to see.

### Encrypted Video on Internet

Here is one encryption scheme that should be much more secure than just putting the video in the .apk. The scheme would require a public key encryption algorithm.

Your program should generate a pair of cryptographic key based on the device's unique ID, sends the public key to the server. The server will encrypt the content using this public key, and then send it to your program. This encrypted content can only be used on this particular device, since only this particular device has the matching private key to decrypt the encrypted content. You don't need to store the private key in the device, it can be generated on-the-fly everytime your program is started. The SD card will contain the encrypted content which can only be decrypted with this particular device.

The drawback of this scheme is you need an algorithm that is light enough for on-the-fly decryption while playing videos. Playing video, by itself, is resource heavy, and decryption is also resource heavy. Also, you need a server that is powerful enough to encrypt the video once each time people install your program.

**How to beat the scheme:** A rooted user would need to extract the .apk from your device, unzip the apk, reverse engineer the .dex files, then figure out the encryption algorithm, extract the private key, and decrypt the video. Alternatively, it is possible for rooted phones to spoof the device ID, which will lead your program to produce a matching private key; this requires unauthorized users to be rooted. This scheme is not fool proof, however unless your content is really that valuable, crackers probably would not go to the trouble of reverse engineering your apk.

### Encrypted Codec

If you really need a truly secure scheme, you will want to use a codec that has built-in encryption. That way, crackers would need to reencode the video -- at the cost of quality loss -- or use a special player -- discouraging people from playing the video.

Comment: Thank you very much for these clear informations. But I've got no knowledge about encryption. I think I'll download them from internet and then just hide them a little bit but I need to find a place not accessible to unrooted phone at least.

Comment: @Trox: that private storage area would be the internal memory, however, if a video-playing app takes 50 MB of my internal memory; that would be an uninstall. Use the SD for large files or you will be uninstalled.

Comment: And is there any folder which is not visible for unrooted phone on the SD card ?

Comment: @Trox: no there isn't; the SD card can be formatted as any filesystem that Linux supports and different manufacturer uses different default file system for SD; some of those file system (e.g. FAT or RFS) does not support access restriction. Alternatively, just use a symmetric encryption algorithm. It isn't as secure as using public-key ecryption algorithm (a.k.a. assymetric encryption), but it is much simpler to use (as in, just pass the file's stream to an API).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to learn how to do symmetric encryption then.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't do that. You should put your videos online somewhere. It doesn't have to be YouTube - it can be a service you host yourself.

Besides, even if you did put the videos inside your application it would still be very easy for your users to copy them and upload them to YouTube so you probably wouldn't gain anything anyway.

Comment: If they are in the APK, first you have to get it (which is not totally easy from the android market) and then open it to get the videos. If you download them from the web you have a file which is totally accessible on your sd card ! In this case I'd need to kind of crypt them so that my app would by the only one to be able to read them. But I don't think it's possible :( .

Comment: @Trox: getting to the .apk is *trivial* if you're rooted; it's just lying there in a nice directory reap for extraction

Comment: For videos game it's not a problem as their data are only usable by them, but for videos... :( Any Idea ?

Comment: @Trox: Only *one* person has to download the videos from the market. Then they can upload a copy of the videos to YouTube and everyone else can view them there. And cryptography won't help because you have to give the secret key to your users so that they can see the video. When you give your secrets to your opponents they're not secrets any more. I'd concentrate on trying to make a good app that people *want* to download instead of fighting a DRM battle against your users.

Comment: @Lie Ryan : Indeed it's easy but you have to be rooted then take the apk and extract it. I don't want my app to be impossible to hack but I just want to be a bit deterrent . Cos if the file is just on your sd card ready to be taken, even the non-hacker will be tempted !

Answer (score 1):

I would either obfuscate the address or make the videos only accessible after authentication.

Comment: When you say "accessible after authentication", it means that the videos are on Internet. I'd like that the users don't have to always have access to Internet. So I'd download them the first time my app is lunched and then store them on the phone. The thing is to hide at least little bit the emplacement of the file or to secure it but I've got no experience with encrypting.

Comment: How would you obfuscate the address ? Is there emplacement on SD card and phone only accessible to rooted phone ?

Comment: @Trox: There are 5 storage places available for any unrooted applications: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: @Lie Ryan : The problem is that Internal storage is private but for small files while External Storage is for big files but it's public. Is there any way to hide at least for unrooted phone a file or a folder ? Or a special location ? Thanks.